# auto load addin call vba in sheet excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How to activate addin, move sheet (auto call vba).

[image]

I'm on a sheet
vba auto load call

activate

```
Sub load()
    If Application.COMAddIns ("iakun"). Connect = True Then
        Application.COMAddIns ("iakun"). Connect = False
        Application.COMAddIns ("iakun"). Connect = True
    Else
        Application.COMAddIns ("iakun"). Connect = True
    End If
End Sub
```

deactivate

```
Sub unload ()
    If Application.COMAddIns ("iakun"). Connect = False Then
        Application.COMAddIns ("iakun"). Connect = True
        Application.COMAddIns ("iakun"). Connect = False
    Else
        Application.COMAddIns ("iakun"). Connect = False
    End If
End Sub
```

move sheet

how to make vba use automatically, without the command. when entering a different sheet.

same

```
Auto_Open Sub ()
    Unload call
End Sub
```

but in sheet

is there a vba code for vba excel auto call (in sheet)

there is a solution?

Comment: Do yo mean something like the [Workbook_SheetActivate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetactivate)? This runs automatically when ever you activate another sheet in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Pᴇʜ 
may I edit my vba code so that it can be done with your intent

Comment: Sorry? Was that a question? I don't get the point of your comment. Please try to write full sentences. Otherwise it is barely understandable. Your original question is also hard to understand.

Comment: Pᴇʜ, 
im try

    Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call unload
    Call load
    End Sub


but vba call code does not run automatically when entering the sheet

something is wrong, with the vba code that I made ?

Comment: Did you put that event code into the `ThisWorkbook` section in the VBA code? It has to be there, and it only runs automatically for the workbook the VBA code is in.

Comment: OK, it works, but how do you make the code, run on sheet1 (vba1), sheet2 (vba2), sheet3 (vba3).

to separate sheets, if this is in the workbook

Comment: What is vba1…3? Please be more precise about what you want to do?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/p8dJuYY.jpg   , vba1, vba2,  (function in sheet excel is different).  Pᴇʜ

Comment: sheet1 runs the vba1 code
move to sheet2 run the vba2 code

Comment: If you want to run a different code on each worksheet you need to put that code into the [Worksheet_Activate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.activate(even)) of the desired worksheet. Note this is another event and the code has to be inside the sheet (in VBA editor) then.

Comment: Hello Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to define your error and efforts in detail.

Comment: okay thank you answer Pᴇʜ, finally i get the answer i want.